# ASUS ZenWiFi ET8 Ethernet backhaul packet loss

Tags: asus, mesh-networking

I'm having significant packet loss when using Ethernet backhaul and I can not figure out the cause. MTR will report as much as 25% packet loss from laptop to LAN server.

I'm able to plug my device directly into the mesh node's Ethernet jack and the packet loss goes away.

```
[LAN Server] - [Switch]
                /     \
               /       \
(2.5gb WAN port)        (2.5gb WAN port)
        |                \
[Mesh leader lan port]  [Mesh node 2.5gb wan port]
|
Laptop
```

I'm looking at this diagram and thinking the nodes need to be direct connected.

Are there guidelines on how to connect these? They communicate and configure each other just fine with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

The asus docs mention plugging satelites nodes into the main node's lan ports. This helped the packet loss significantly

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue earlier today with my ET12. The problem ended up being a faulty ethernet cable and had nothing to do with the actual router.